# What exactly does primary key mean in sql

Tags: sql

I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

but I can't understand the purpose of the primary key

```
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
```

in that table.

Comment: Please elaborate. You've written a `CREATE TABLE` statement and you can't understand why you added `PRIMARY KEY(P_Id)` ?

Comment: [Primary Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)

Comment: for eg user1999109 is ur primary user id key on stackoverflow.. can 2 people have the same user id ? so thts wht a primary key is for..

Comment: Read http://bit.ly/XH1jj5 and learn the fundamental basics of database design

Comment: There is a logical meaning, which is - PK uniquely identifies each row in your table. There is also physical implementation "meaning" that will be different in each RDBMS and have it's own consequences, like indexes, ordering in queries, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> A table typically has a column or combination of columns that contain
>   values that uniquely identify each row in the table. This column, or
>   columns, is called the primary key (PK) of the table and enforces the
>   entity integrity of the table. You can create a primary key by
>   defining a PRIMARY KEY constraint when you create or modify a table.